# How to using static classes in other project

Tags: c#, .net

Okay I have a class clsA in **project A.** I want to use static methods of clsA in **project B**.

I have tried to call these static functions by using the classname i.e clsA.function() in project B. But it's throwing error **"The name clsA does not exists in the current context"**

how do I solve this? Do I need to reference the class in project or something? If so then how to do it?

Comment: Yes, you need a reference from project B to project A, then you will probably need a `using` directive to import the namespace containing `clasA`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile projectA and then add that dll as a reference to project B. You also need to add the namespace to the top of clsB.

Comment: One: there is no namespace defined in clsA. Two:How do I find out the dll name that corresponds to clsA?.

Comment: @user3452275: If you'd provided a short but complete example of all of this, we wouldn't have to guess... but if `clsA` isn't declared in a namespace (which it should be for any production code) then you won't need a using directive.

Comment: Dll goes in the bin directory after you compile it. Bin directory is located under project dir. Right click the project in vs and then click open folder in file explorer. Bin should be there which will have your dll.

Comment: @john Paul Yes, but how can I figure out which dll to use?

Comment: Project A assembly name is located in the application portion of the project properties.

Comment: Would you please elaborate a lilttle bit?